# Handling Multiple JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, json, performance, jquery

If I have a function like this, i pass in a variable of movieid.

```
function getFilmDetails(movieid) {
    var filmDetails = 0;


    $.ajax({

        dataType: "json",
        type: 'get',
        mimeType: "textPlain",
        url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + movieid,
        async: false,
        success: function(result){

             if(result.popularity > 10000) {
                 result.popularity = 10000;
            } 
            if(result.popularity < 0.1) {
                 result.popularity = 0.1;
            } 

            filmDetails = result;
        }
    });

    return filmDetails;
}
```

I'm calling over 100 films details through this function and as you can imagine, it takes forever to load the page by doing it this way. I need to easily access the values in the JSON for each film. For example:

```
alert(getFilmDetails(12345).description);
alert(getFilmDetails(65432).popularity);
alert(getFilmDetails(12345).tagline);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're using `async:false;`... why? Have your function accept a callback. `getFilmDetails(12345, function(data) { alert(data); })`  Then inside your function, inplace of the `filmDetails = result;`, invoke the callback, and pass it `result`, like `callback(result);`

Comment: You should not fire over 100 ajax (and neither 100 sjax) requests from a single page

Answer (score 1):

```
    // receive a callback------------v
function getFilmDetails(movieid, callback) {
    var filmDetails = 0;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'get',
        mimeType: "textPlain",
        url: 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + movieid,
//        async: false,  // YUCK! Commented out

        success: function(result){

            if(result.popularity > 10000) {
                 result.popularity = 10000;
            } 
            if(result.popularity < 0.1) {
                 result.popularity = 0.1;
            } 
            callback(result) // invoke your callback
    });
    return filmDetails;
}
```

---

```
  // make a callback
function workWithData(data) {
    alert(data.description);
}

  // pass the callback
getFilmDetails(12345, workWithData);
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can pass the call backed data into an array which contains multiple result sets. The code above works, but if I try to push it into an array, the value is not returned when called outside the function.

Comment: @AntonCooper: Most important thing is to break away from hoping things will happen in a simple, synchronous order. The way to approach these async issues is to find creative ways to accomplish what you want. For example if you know you're going to make `100` requests, and you want your callback to do something special after the last request is done, you could maintain a counter that equals the number of requests you're making, then have each callback decrement the counter. When the counter reaches `0`, you know the last response came back, so that callback can work with the full Array of data.

Comment: @thesystem may be i am asking something funny but i am just curious to ask that why you added a callback? Is it just because you want to access the data in JSON format?

Comment: @Peeyush: The callback doesn't have anything to do with the data format. It just allows a person to deal with the code that runs out of order. Because the rest of the code *(below the `getFilmDetails(...)` call)* won't wait for the data to return before running, any code that uses the fetched data *(when it finally arrives)* must be invoked inside the `success:` callback. Passing another callback to the `success:` callback is a nice way to pass the necessary code into the function doing the AJAX request.